# Axolot's XLSReadWriteII 5 component destroys xls file's strings when writing TWideMemo data

Tags: sql-server, excel, delphi, unicode

I am using Delphi XE10 on windows7 and I've built an application in which I try to create an xls file with XLSReadWriteII 5 component.
Specifically I am reading data that has been stored previously in an sql table and exporting it to an xls file.

Now, while everything works fine with ASCII data, when I try to write Unicode data to the relative worksheet I am facing problem whenever I am parsing ntext sql fields (that contain Unicode strings). As all we know ntext sql's fields are handled by Delphi-XE10 as TWideMemo fields, which is the appropriate data-type field to handle Unicode data.

However, XLSReadWriteII 5 component (even though built for Unicode data), not only does not write TWideMemo field's value in the xls file, but worst, it destroys any string data in any cell of the file that previously has written itself leaving only untouchable any numeric-type data. And the most bizzare of all is that it does not creating any error during the writing procedure, which i would be able to catch and solve it.
On the contrary, it executes the appropriate procedure like everything is fine (as it would be if it was about to write ASCII data only) and then when you try to open the xls file (either with excel or open-office), it gives you a couple of warning messages and after that you can only see cells with numeric-type data and no string at all !!!

I am facing this strange behavious of XLS-component only when parsing ntext fields. When parsing nvarchar fields then no problem at all !!

Here I give you the code which I use in my application:

```
Procedure WriteDataToCell(adoQ:Tadoquery;row,col,fcol:integer);
var 
   inh:string; data_type:TfieldType;  XLappSun:TXLSReadWriteII5;  sheetSun:Txlsworksheet;
begin
   sheetsun:=xlappsun.SheetByName('sheet1'); 
   data_type:=AdoQ.Fields[fcol].DataType;
   case data_type  of
     ftdate,fttime,ftdatetime,ftTimeStamp: 
           begin
             inh:= formatdatetime('dd/mm/yyyy',AdoQ.Fields[fcol].value);
             sheetsun.asdatetime[col,row-1]:=AdoQ.Fields[fcol].value+0;
           end;
     ftboolean:  
           begin
                 case AdoQ.Fields[fcol].asboolean of
                      true : sheetsun.AsInteger[col,row-1]:=1;
                      false: sheetsun.AsInteger[col,row-1]:=0;
                 end;
           end;
     ftSmallint,ftInteger,ftWord,ftAutoInc,ftLargeint: 
           begin
                sheetsun.asinteger[col,row-1]:=AdoQ.Fields[fcol].asinteger;
           end;
     ftmemo,ftFmtMemo,ftwideMemo:
           begin
               try
                  sheetsun.Asstring[col,row-1]:=AdoQ.Fields[fcol].AsString ;
               except
                  sheetsun.Asstring[col,row-1]:='*****';
               end;
           end;
     ftblob,ftgraphic :
        begin
           sheetsun.Asstring[col,row-1]:='';
        end;
     ftFloat,ftCurrency,ftBCD:
        begin
           sheetsun.AsFloat[col,row-1]:=AdoQ.Fields[fcol].Value;
        end;
     else
          try
             sheetsun.Asstring[col,row-1]:=AdoQ.Fields[fcol].AsString;
          except
             sheetsun.Asstring[col,row-1]:='*****';
          end;
   end;
end;
```

I Also have to say that the data which I store in the ntext field of my sql table is being provided through an RTF Edit-box in the relevant form, so that to be able giving specific formatting to the UNICODE text I want to store (In cases I want to give specific format like Bold, Underline etc...).
Maybe this is the reason of the problem ... I don't know...

Here is the DML code

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UnicodeT] (
    [countryid] [int] NOT NULL ,
    [Country] [nvarchar] (50) COLLATE Greek_CI_AS NULL ,
    [Comments] [ntext] COLLATE Greek_CI_AS NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

And Here is a snap of my data:

1. Αυτό το αυτοκίνητο κινείτε πολύ γρήγορα και επικίνδυνα σε αυτόν τον στενό δρόμο  - Greek
2. This car is very fast and dangerous in this narrow street   -  English
3. 这辆车是在这个狭窄的街道非常快速和危险   -   Chinese_simplified
4. Tento vůz je velmi rychlá a nebezpečná v této úzké uličce    -   Chez
5. ეს მანქანა არის ძალიან სწრაფი და საშიში ამ ვიწრო ქუჩაზე   -  Georgian
6. המכונית הזאת היא מאוד מהירה ומסוכנת הרחוב הצר הזה  -  Hebrew
7. Þessi bíll er mjög fljótur og hættulegur í þessum þrönga götu   -  Icelandic
8. この車はこの狭い通りに非常に高速かつ危険です   -   Japanese
9. ಈ ಕಾರು ಈ ಕಿರಿದಾದ ರಸ್ತೆಯಲ್ಲಿ ಅತ್ಯಂತ ವೇಗವಾಗಿ ಮತ್ತು ಅಪಾಯಕಾರಿ    -    Kannada
10. این خودرو بسیار سریع و خطرناک در این خیابان باریک است    -  Persian

The above data is the same phrase that is being given in 10 different languages

I would appreciate any possible help....

Thank you in advance

Comment: You'd have much better luck posting this on the [Axolot XLSReadWriteII5 forums](http://www.axolot.com/BB3/index.php). Lars is extremely knowledgeable about the code, and usually responds within 24 hours or so. You should always try the vendor's own support forums first before posting here. You should probably also include some representative text that is causing the issue, so that people can try to reproduce it and help solve the problem. Without test data, it's pretty much impossible. Lars will most likely ask you to email him a sample file. (Is it XLS or XLSX that you're having issues with?)

Comment: Hi Ken. Firstly, if you miss that Lars doesn't answer in each issue. Secondly, I did post and If you are right he will respond in the next 16 hours. Lastly, its not so hard for one to create a simple sql table with two fields - one as nvarchar(50) and the other as ntext - and provide a few records with Unicode strings. Then create in xe-10 a simple app with one form in which he will add an XLSReadWriteII 5 component, an adoQuery, an AdoConnection and a speed button that triggers my procedure to create the xls file. So why including representative text ?(Problem appears in both xls or xlsx)

Comment: Even though I believe that one could simply use google - or any other translator - to create ,with a simple line, a bunch of Unicode translations in several languages and thus use them, I can provide such data If you insist....

Comment: I'm sorry. You want me to go out and spend the effort to collect data to try and use to solve **your problem**, in addition to any effort I would make actually testing and helping to solve it? Afraid that's not how this site works. It's **your responsibility** to provide the necessary information to us, **in your question**. If Google Translate will provide *a bunch of Unicode translations*, please do that and include them. When you do, include the DML statements to create the table and insert the data, and then you can include a small MCVE that demonstrates the problem that we can compile.

Comment: And yes, I have the latest version of XLSRWII5 to use in compiling the code from your MCVE once you've posted it. FWIW, I think it's incredible that you would post here and say *Here's a problem I'm having. If you need sample data to reproduce it, go Google Translate some stuff yourself.*

Comment: Well, ... I think you have taken it all wrong from the beginning. Firstly, I would never ask one to create data if it wouldn't be really easy - even for a 5 years-old boy. Secondly it would be a mistake to provide such data just in plain text and thus make the question soooooooooooooo long to read (If I could attach a file I would happily do it, but you see there is no such capability. However, just for you I'll provide this). We are supposed not to tire possible helpers by reading needless stuff if you can remember how this site works !!!!!  Moreover, I didn't provide DML statements because..

Comment: Except sample data is not *needless stuff*. It's relevant to the question. Second, you don't need lots and lots of data; the bare minimum to recreate the issue will suffice, which should only mean a few lines of text. Third, if **you** will remember how this site works, it's **your job** to write the question and provide the necessary information, and once you've done that we can try to help. You have to do **your job** first. There's a reason your question has collected 4 close votes, and it's  because you've not yet done your half. Please do so instead of making excuses about why you haven't

Comment: I don't know which version of sql you are using and with what settings you are creating your tables and your DB's of yours. But I know one thing for sure and that is if for example I use sql2000 and you use sql2014 - or later -  then my DML statements won't really create the table you are asking from me, since these two versions of sql are not compatible. If I am wrong, please do correct me

Comment: Ok... I apologise for any possible mistake I may did without intentding to. Here data for one to use (at least I'll try to pass it...)
Αυτό το αυτοκίνητο κινείτε πολύ γρήγορα και επικίνδυνα σε αυτόν τον στενό δρόμο-Greek,This car is very fast and dangerous in this narrow street-English,Այս մեքենան շատ արագ է եւ վտանգավոր է այս նեղ փողոցում-Armenian,Тази кола е много бърз и опасен в тази тясна улица-Bulgarian, 这辆车是在这个狭窄的街道非常快速和危险-Chinese_simplified ეს მანქანა არის ძალიან სწრაფი და საშიში ამ ვიწრო ქუჩაზე-Georgian,Þessi bíll er mjög fljótur og hættulegur í þessum þrönga götu-Icelandic

Comment: Oh, good grief. You need to [edit] your question and add the data there, where it can be seen (and where it can be copied/pasted). Don't ever bury important information in comments; put it in the question where it's available for everyone to see. (For future reference, the [edit] link can be found right below the tags in your question. You can always edit your own question.) And post your DML anyway. The `CREATE TABLE` DML has not changed drastically between SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 2014, and the backward-compatibility support is always pretty good in MS products.

Comment: Since I edited and provided DML and Unicode data why my question is still held as **of topic ?**

Comment: Because you need to learn to be patient. It takes multiple votes to close it, and it takes multiple votes to reopen once it's improved. (If you'd  listened to me in the first place, it would never have been closed, and you would have had an answer by now. Keep that in mind in the future - when you're asked to provide more information, **do it**. instead of arguing) You don't get everything immediately - this is not a quick service site. Your question will get attention. Wait for it.

Comment: Hi Ken, i would like to say that it wasn't my intention to argue with anyone. And i already know that this isn't a quick service site, so i don't have any time demands at all. Usually, i provide all the pieces that compose the problem i am facing (at least most of the times). However this time, unfortunately, i thought (as you can see from the DML and the Unicode data) that for simplicity reasons and trying to avoid making the question boring that there was no need to provide them. It seems that i was wrong...

Comment: *i don't have any time demands at all* - Then why, 17 minutes after you added the necessary information, are you asking *why my question is still held as of topic?*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not with XLSReadWriteII5. The issue is with your DB driver or your code that is producing the XLSX file. Here's the test I conducted to make that determination using Delphi 10 Seattle v23.0.21418.4207 and XLSReadWriteII5 v5.20.70:

- Create a new VCL Forms application
- Add a single *TButton* to the form.
- Add the following code to the form, changing the name of the `TestFile` to a suitable location on your own system and connecting the `TButton.OnClick` event to the `TForm1.Button1Click` method.

  ```
  unit Unit1;

  interface

  uses
    Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
    Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

  type
    TForm1 = class(TForm)
      Button1: TButton;
      procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
      procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    private
      { Private declarations }
    public
      { Public declarations }
    end;

  var
    Form3: TForm3;

  implementation

  {$R *.dfm}

  uses
    XLSReadWriteII5, XLSCmdFormat5, XLSSheetData5, xc12DataStyleSheet5, Xc12Utils5;

  const
    TestFile = 'E:\TempFiles\UnicodeTest.xlsx';

    aStrings: array[0..5] of String =
      ('Αυτό το αυτοκίνητο κινείτε πολύ γρήγορα και επικίνδυνα σε αυτόν τον στενό δρόμο',
       'This car is very fast and dangerous in this narrow street ',
       '这辆车是在这个狭窄的街道非常快速和危险',
       'Tento vůz je velmi rychlá a nebezpečná v této úzké uličce',
       'ეს მანქანა არის ძალიან სწრაფი და საშიში ამ ვიწრო ქუჩაზე',
       'המכונית הזאת היא מאוד מהירה ומסוכנת הרחוב הצר הזה');

  procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  var
    XLS: TXLSReadWriteII5;
    i: Integer;
  begin
    XLS := TXLSReadWriteII5.Create(nil);
    XLS.LoadFromFile(TestFile);
    for i := Low(aStrings) to High(aStrings) do
      XLS[0].AsString[5, i] := aStrings[i];

    XLS.Write;
    XLS.Free;
    ShowMessage('Done');
  end;

  procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  var
    XLS: TXLSReadWriteII5;
  begin
    XLS := TXLSReadWriteII5.Create(nil);
    XLS[0].AsString[0, 0] := 'This is test ANSI text';
    XLS[0].AsString[0, 1] := 'This is more ANSI text';
    XLS[0].AsInteger[0, 2] := 123;
    XLS[0].AsFloat[0, 3] := 345.67;
    XLS.SaveToFile(TestFile);
  end;

  end.
  ```
- Run the application, which will create the XLSX file with the ANSI text and numeric content in `FormCreate`.
- Without clicking the button, open the file in Excel and confirm the contents match the below image, and then exit from Excel:

[image: Excel sheet with ANSI text, integer, and float values]

- Click the button, which adds the first 6 items from your sample data (the ones numbered 1..6) to column `F` of the spreadsheet, on the same rows as the existing data we wrote before.
- Open the sheet again in Excel, which now contains the content in the below image.

[image: Same Excel sheet, now containing additional Unicode strings]

Note that the second image contains the proper Unicode content (including the RTL Hebrew text), and that there are no error messages displayed by Excel. The original ANSI strings, integer, and float values are also correctly displayed, and everything is in it's proper location.

The above indicates that the issue is not with how XLSReadWriteII5 is writing the Unicode, but is instead either in the configuration of your database character set, the DBMS components you're using, or your Delphi code itself. It is not, however, an issue with XLSReadWriteII5 and writing Unicode strings.

Updated: The OP keeps insisting that XLSReadWriteII5 is unable to correctly write strings when read from an ADO table memo field. Here's an updated version of the button click event that proves that's wrong:

DML (Advantage Database Server v10.10, because that's what's handy):

```
Create Table UCodeTest (ID numeric(2, 0), Content NMEMO);
insert into UCodeTest (ID, Content) 
  Values (1, 'Αυτό το αυτοκίνητο κινείτε πολύ γρήγορα και επικίνδυνα σε αυτόν τον στενό δρόμο');
insert into UCodeTest (ID, Content)
  Values (2, 'This car is very fast and dangerous in this narrow street ');
insert into UCodeTest (ID, Content)
  Values (3, '这辆车是在这个狭窄的街道非常快速和危险');
insert into UCodeTest (ID, Content)
  Values (4, 'Tento vůz je velmi rychlá a nebezpečná v této úzké uličce');
insert into UCodeTest (ID, Content)
  Values (5, 'ეს მანქანა არის ძალიან სწრაფი და საშიში ამ ვიწრო ქუჩაზე');
insert into UCodeTest (ID, Content)
  Values (6, 'המכונית הזאת היא מאוד מהירה ומסוכנת הרחוב הצר הזה');
```

Button click event:

```
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  XLS: TXLSReadWriteII5;
  i: Integer;
begin
  XLS := TXLSReadWriteII5.Create(nil);
  XLS.LoadFromFile(TestFile);
  ADOQuery1.Open;
  i := 0;
  while not ADOQuery1.Eof do
  begin
    XLS[0].AsString[5, i] := ADOQuery1.FieldByName('Content').AsString;
    Inc(i);
    ADOQuery1.Next;
  end;
  XLS.Write;
  XLS.Free;
  ADOQuery1.Close;
  ShowMessage('Done');
end;
```

New Excel workbook content, showing that data read back from Unicode memo fields work fine, and once again confirming that the problem is not in XLSReadWriteII5:

[image]

Comment: Hi Ken. As i see first you create an xls(or xlsx file) by saving some random strings (or general data) in it during the FormCreate procedure. Then you pass the values that are stored in an array and finally you execute the write and free procedures of xls. The differences from mine procedure is that a) i don't initially save some data to the file and b) idon't call the write and free procedures....That is because I've put an xls component on my form and i don't creating it on run time. And with ASCII i never had problem. I guess that if i call the write and free procedure would fix the problem

Comment: Now about my DB configuration i can say that it doesn't produce any problem because this would be obvious no matter what kind of strings i am storing to and parsing from. As for my DBMS components these are the Delphi's ones picked from the  db tab (AdoConnection, AdoQuery). So i don't think that its my fault. Instead i think that either axolot is malfunctioning or smth else. .... Except if - as i said before - i should call in the end the write procedure of the XLS component

Comment: Your question says *XLSReadWriteII 5 component (even though built for Unicode data), not only does not write TWideMemo field's value in the xls file, but worst, it destroys any string data in any cell of the file that previously has written itself leaving only untouchable any numeric-type data.* I've proven that it does **NOT** destroy any string data in existing cells, and that it **DOES** in fact properly write Unicode strings in the XLSX file. It's not TXLSReadWriteII5, and my code proves that fact. So yes, it much be *smth else*. Figure out what and ask about that instead.

Comment: *idont' call the write and free procedures*. If you're not writing the file, you can't see that the data is corrupted. Your question is making less and less sense the more you try to explain. The fact it's on the form and not created at runtime is irrelevant to the issue, and you cannot call free on the component if you're dropping it on the form at designtime; the form will free it when the form is closing. `XLS.Write` (or `XLS.SaveToFile()` are what write the spreadsheet to disk, and if you're not doing that you're not saving any data in the spreadsheet and your problem doesn't exist.

Comment: You are right Ken, i call the `XLS.SaveToFile()` function after parsing all the data i want to right in my xls or xlsx file. As for whether XLSRWII destroys string when parsing TWideMemo fields, i would say that your example does not parse any TWideMemo field of an AdoQuery. Instead you are giving the Unicode data through an already created array which is different case. It's the TWideMemo data field that XLSRWII can not comply with

Comment: You're not paying attention.  :-) TWideMemo data fields contain WideStrings, which are Unicode strings. My test code shows that it's not XLSReadWriteII5 that is causing any corruption of the values, because it correctly writes Unicode text to a worksheet, and does not corrupt any existing values in that worksheet. That indicates that the problem lies elsewhere. Figure out where. It doesn't matter how much you insist that the problem  exists  in XLSReadWriteII instead of other code; I've proven that is not the case with the test code here. Again you're arguing instead of paying attention,.

Comment: Ok.. I do pay attention and not arguing. I also know that TWideMemo contains WideStrings. However how comes when one provides XLSRWII widestrings through any possible DataSource than TWideMemo then XLSRWII does what is meant to do, but when you provide the same DataSource through TWideMemo it just erases any possible string in the file ? So I guess that a possible explanation is that smth goes wrong between XLSRWII and TWideMemo fields that retrieve their data from a DB.... Otherwise the work-around I just post wouldn't solve this malfunction of XLS's

Comment: No, something goes wrong when reading TWideMemo fields, because XLSRWII does not read them. Your code does, and passes them to XLSRWII via the `AsString[]` property. I'm going to repeat one more time, because apparently you can't hear me: **This is NOT and XLSReadWriteII5 issue.** XLSRWII does not **retrieve data from a DB** in the code you posted. `AdoQ.Fields[fcol].AsString` clearly indicates that `AdoQ` is what's *retrieving data from a DB*.

Comment: However, putting a watch or the cursor or even post to a message the value of the `AdoQ.Fields[fcol].AsString` of the specific Query that parses then ntext field - which you indicate as the element i should inspect - then i am taking the value i should take. So at that point what goes wrong and this value can not pass to XLSRWII ?. If it was my mistake then i shouldn't retrieve at all the Unicode data or i should retrieve rubish.  So probably **its XLSRWII fault**  that doesn't comply with AdoQuery in case of TWideMemo fields, which value's you can pass or post in any other form....

Comment: I'll post an updated example, which creates a table, populates it with the same strings I used in the array, and then reads the Unicode memo field back and writes to XLSRWII5 **and does not demonstrate the same problem you've described**. Once again, **XLSRWII5** is not the issue, because I"ve proven it works properly when writing Unicode strings.

Comment: Example posted. **Argue and whine all you want - the problem is not in XLSReadWriteII5 and it's handling of Unicode strings, read from ADO or not.** I showed that your hacky workaround is not the solution, because the problem does not exist in XLSReadWriteII5; my code does not pass the content through a TDBMemo first, but reads directly from the DB and writes to the XLSX without issue.

Comment: I would really like to see your example that should include as you taught me the DML code too as well as the Unicode strings and the Delphi procedures. And i will test them both in sql2014 and sql2008. I would be really glad to see that things are as you say and not as i say. That will probably help me find the problem in case you are right

Comment: My DML code is right there, in my edited content. I even marked it as such, and I used your own Unicode strings, and I provided the Delphi procedures - the code is right there, in my edited content. I even marked it as **UPDATED** so you could easily find it.

Comment: I respect your experience and your knowledge and i declare that i am not so experienced as you are. So it would really help me - as well as the forum - your example. I am not arguing, not disrespecting. I only try to show - except if i am wrong - that under specific situations XLSRWII is not working as it should. Nothing more. Just provide the similar to my scenario example of yours and then i will be persuaded and by you a drinkk :) (just a joke for the last, no offence)

Comment: ok .. ive got to go for now. I'll be back in one hour and test your code. Then i'll see and post my conclusions.

Comment: I just provided that example, with DML, code, and results. Now **you** create a new project, that does nothing but query the DB and write the single memo field to a spreadsheet, without any of the other noise that your post contains? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), write one, and post it. That example should contain none of the stuff with field types, if or case statements, and should be about the size of my code example.

Comment: On second thought, don't bother. I've answered the question you asked here, which is about XLSReadWriteII5 and Unicode strings, and I've proven that XLSReadWriteII5 has no issue with Unicode strings, whether they come from an array or an ADO query. You're not going to listen anyway, because you're ignoring multiple proofs that you're wrong, and you refuse to hear any answers that don't say what you want them to say. I've wasted far too much time here already. Good luck to you.

Comment: Since I always honor the one who helps me I have to notice that after too  much debugging and after running your example I realized that, unfortunately for me, the malfunction is produced by the Infopower RichTextEdit control that I use in combination with the infopower grid. The combination of these two controls sends to the sql formation of the input text that XLSRWII component can not recognize and thus creates this situation. Eventually, you were right from the beginning. I just didn't believe that Infopowers controls - which works so fine in Delphi 7 - create such situations in XE-10

Comment: Thanks. :-)  Perhaps in the future you might pay more attention to answers you receive, especially those that provide code that specifically addresses the issue. My first comment to you yesterday was posted at 14:00 UTC, and here (a day later at 22:30 UTC) you've realized that you've wasted an entire day. If you had listened from the beginning, this would have been resolved yesterday - you would have provided the details I asked for, I could have written the same answer, you could have listened to that answer and looked elsewhere sooner, and found the issue with the InfoPower controls faster.

Comment: As far as InfoPower controls creating such issues, have you upgraded them from the D2007 versions to a more recent one? There was a huge transition in Delphi in D2009 when things went from AnsiString to UnicodeString, and third-party controls had to be changed to support the differences in many cases. If you're still using the D2007 version, those changes weren't made, and the problem isn't with InfoPower - it's with you for not upgrading those controls.

Comment: Hi Ken, you are totally right. I just miconfused DBMS controls with only the ones that connects you to the DB (I was too confident for Infopower's components....). Just for the record I used to built my applications with Delphi 7 and Infopower suite 4000. I've recently upgrated to Delphi xe-10 since I had to handle Unicode data and thus I updated my Infopower suite to the appropriate one to cooperate with the xe-10 suite (that is the last one). I haven't though used at all the Firepower components of Infopower. But now I am starting thinking of migrating to DevExpress components.....

Comment: By the way I still have to buy you that drink :)

Answer (score -1):

I found a work-around, which doesn't really explains why XLS reacts like that in TWideMemo, but at least provides a solution.

Specifically i create on run-time a Delphi component of TDBMemo (or i can put it in design-time on my form... maybe better...) in which i pass the AdoQ's Data-Source and then pass TDBMemo's value to XLS.
This is how it works:

```
Procedure WriteDataToCell(adoQ:Tadoquery;row,col,fcol:integer);
var 
   inh:string; data_type:TfieldType;  XLappSun:TXLSReadWriteII5; sheetSun:Txlsworksheet;  
    MyMemo:TDBMemo;
begin
   sheetsun:=xlappsun.SheetByName('sheet1'); 
   data_type:=AdoQ.Fields[fcol].DataType;
   case data_type  of
      ftdate,fttime,ftdatetime,ftTimeStamp: 
       begin
         inh:= formatdatetime('dd/mm/yyyy',AdoQ.Fields[fcol].value);
         sheetsun.asdatetime[col,row-1]:=AdoQ.Fields[fcol].value+0;
       end;
 ftboolean:  
       begin
             case AdoQ.Fields[fcol].asboolean of
                  true : sheetsun.AsInteger[col,row-1]:=1;
                  false: sheetsun.AsInteger[col,row-1]:=0;
             end;
       end;
 ftSmallint,ftInteger,ftWord,ftAutoInc,ftLargeint: 
       begin
            sheetsun.asinteger[col,row-1]:=AdoQ.Fields[fcol].asinteger;
       end;
 ftmemo,ftFmtMemo,ftwideMemo:
       begin
           MyMemo.Create(nil);
           try
              MyMemo.DataSource:= AdoQ.DataSource; 
              sheetsun.Asstring[col,row-1]:=MyMemo.DataSource.DataSet.Fields[fcol].AsString ; 
          //    sheetsun.Asstring[col,row-1]:=AdoQ.Fields[fcol].AsString ;
           except
              sheetsun.Asstring[col,row-1]:='*****';
           end;
           MyMemo.free;
       end;
 ftblob,ftgraphic :
    begin
       sheetsun.Asstring[col,row-1]:='';
    end;
 ftFloat,ftCurrency,ftBCD:
    begin
       sheetsun.AsFloat[col,row-1]:=AdoQ.Fields[fcol].Value;
    end;
 else
      try
         sheetsun.Asstring[col,row-1]:=AdoQ.Fields[fcol].AsString;
      except
         sheetsun.Asstring[col,row-1]:='*****';
      end;
  end;
end;
```

That way i can retrieve any character's set Unicode data of ntext data-type and also keep any possible formation.

As i said in the beginning of my answer, this work-around doesn't really explain why XLS reacts like that or whether one should use another property or function of XLSRWII component in order to retrieve data from TWideMemo fields. This is for axolot to find out...

Comment: I'm  downvoting this answer, because it's not an answer to the question asked, which was about XLSReadWriteII5 and Unicode strings. You've added a workaround to a problem that is not related to XLSReadWriteII5 and it's handling of Unicode strings and again blamed it on the wrong code. It's misleading to future readers here.

Comment: As i explained above, i added a problem that XLSRWII creates when one pass to it a value from a TWideMemo field that belongs to an AdoQuery connected to a DB. I aslo found and posted a work-around to this misbehavior of XLSRWII. Also Lars from axolot haven't found yet neither a solution or an explanation for this phenomenon. I suggest that we should let all the other users to decide themselves whether my solution is beneficial or not for them by giving them the chance to decide for their own mind. (Moderators votes can easily change people minds without testing the solution, no offence)

Comment: See my updated answer, which shows that use of the DBMemo is not necessary. You can read directly from the ADOQuery field using `AsString` and write using `XLS[0].AsString[Col, Row]` without issue. **XLSRW** does not read from a memo field - I don't know why you can't comprehend that, but it's true. Your code clearly shows that the **ADOQuery** is reading from the field and passing that content to XLSRWII when you assign it using `:=`.